# Guava Return keys with value above some threshold

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, guava

I have this code to take a map and sort it by key 
I then reverse the map to get them with the largest elements first.

```
Ordering<String> valueComparator = 
       Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(WordMap))
                         .compound(Ordering.natural());

WordMapSorted = ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(WordMap, 
                                  Collections.reverseOrder(valueComparator));
```

I'd like to know two things

1. How can I get only the keys with a value above 10? I feel like given the sorting with guava there should be an easy way to specify a cutoff point (since once you reach a value below the threshold, you simply get all the items before it)
2. How can I get the first 100 entries in the map (still in the form of a map). I know I can just get an array of keys and get the first 100, but I want the first 100 map entries. I know that normally a map has no order, but in this case it was sorted and made immutable so it does have order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First observation: there's no need to use `Collections.reverseOrder(valueComparator)`, when you can just use `valueComparator.reverse()`.

1 requires some trickiness:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(WordMapSorted.values().asList(), 11);
index = (index >= 0) ? index : -index - 1;
// the elements at and after index have value strictly greater than 10
return WordMapSorted.keySet().asList().subList(index, WordMapSorted.size());
```

2 is doable like so:

```
WordMapSorted.headMap(WordMapSorted.keySet().asList().get(100));
```

Comment: good point, I wasn't sure if reverse actually did extra work. thanks for the second answer that's very helpful! i suppose i could just iterate through the map with an iterator and stop when i reach the given value..

Comment: also sorry what do you mean by headMap?

Comment: @Lemonio: What do you mean, what do I mean by `headMap`?  It's a method, available for all `SortedMap`s.

Comment: oops nvm i mispelled it when I googled it -.-. thank you! the first answer is super elegant I didn't know there were binary search or sublist methods. never really used collections haha

Comment: in the first answer is it just they keys or both keys and values?

Comment: The first answer just returns keys because you asked for the keys.  If you want the result as a `Map`, then just do `WordMapSorted.tailMap(WordMapSorted.keySet().asList().get(index))`.

Comment: could you explain how this line works? i understand how everything works after looking at the javadocs, but not sure where the 10 comes in here. index = (index >= 0) ? index : -index - 1;

Comment: It doesn't come in there; it comes in at the previous line, when we `binarySearch` with a key of 11, which is the smallest integer greater than 10.